# I receive an error (springSecurityFilterChain appears twice) Spring Security migration Jetty 7 to 9

Tags: java, spring-security

In my project,  I use Spring Security and Jetty.
Now, I use Jetty 7 and I want to migrate to Jetty 9 (just to be up to date).

With Jetty 7, my project run perfectly but if I migrate to 9 I receive an error message when it starts:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate Filter registration for 'springSecurityFilterChain'. Check to ensure the Filter is only configured once.

I use annotation and this is the configuration:

Maven:

```xml
<properties>
    <!-- NOT LATEST VERSION -->
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.9.4.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>

    <!-- LATEST VERSION -->
    <springframework.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <spring-security.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.9</aspectj.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>5.2.4.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    <cglib.version>3.2.4</cglib.version>

    <!-- No compatibility needed -->
    <mysql.version>6.0.3</mysql.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.21</slf4j.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.192</h2.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <javax-servlet.version>3.1.0</javax-servlet.version>
    <jsp-api.version>2.3.1</jsp-api.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <taglibs.version>1.1.2</taglibs.version>
</properties>
```

I have this classes:

```
/config/JpaConfiguration.java
/config/LoggingConfiguration.java
/config/MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java
/config/SecurityAuthenticationFailureHandler.java
/config/SecurityAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java
/config/SecurityConfig.java
/config/SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java
/config/WebConfiguration.java
```

And the web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.jle.athleges.config.LoggingConfiguration
            com.jle.athleges.config.JpaConfiguration
            com.jle.athleges.config.WebConfiguration
            com.jle.athleges.config.SecurityConfig
         </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- START: Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. I moved to AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer and implements methods and removed the configuration in web.xml.
Great !

Answer (score 0):

You have two definitions of bean `springSecurityFilterChain`:

1. With `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java` (since Servlet 3.0+):

   See [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer)
2. With `web.xml`:

   ```
   <filter>
       <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
   </filter>
   ```

Remove one of two definitions.